# Deploy contract into polygon mainnet get err: max fee per gas less than block base fee:

Tags: truffle

Currently, I have an error: `max fee per gas less than block base fee` when trying to deploy on Polygon mainnet using Truffle. How can I solve the gas fee problem?

```
matic: {
    provider: function () {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
        [process.env.DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY],
        `https://polygon-rpc.com`
    );
},
network_id: 137,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding gasprice in truffle.config will fixed the issue.